# MTA (postfix) failing on one domain relay of a dual domain config

Tags: postfix, email-server, spf

I want MTA to send emails from 2 domains, issues by same server. eEmail is sending from one domain, but failing from the other.

My app server generates smtp email as either **mydomain.com** or **mydomainother.com**

App server lives on

```
ipv4: 1.1.1.1 ipv6: 1111:1111:...0001
```

and serves pages as mydomainother.com

Either way it sends to same MTA on server 2

mta lives at

```
ipv4: 1.1.1.2 ipv6: 1111:1111:...0002
```

Brochure site for mydomain.com lives at 
ipv4: 1.1.1.3

Mailserver for mydomain.com is outlook (don't mock, I didn't choose)

The MTA is postfix, with opendkim add-on. 
It receives and relays mails correctly for mydomainother.com
It fails when relaying mails from mydomain.com with google SPF failures bouncing them back

mydomainother.com has these DNS entries:

```
inventryanywhere.co.uk. 14400   IN  TXT v=spf1 mx a ip4:1.1.1.1/32 ip4:1.1.1.2 ip6:1111:1111:...0002/128 ?all
dkim._domainkey.mydomainother.com.  600 IN  TXT v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCt79QysuOC7QU2h0w7eKSZyptVkZkPD/zqTqmzq3ZNpqz5YmunBatGhESYea5RX51CpQHbcH0gmAN0tXvz7jCIi+2xyDyVe+Ay/EW4D72DNU+a0Ckr6lPdsS0lpNg7A8/RzDO4+m2n1E7ZrImFp+3MZz6q5pQPm5DzqOoDCTTRnQIDAQAB; s=email
```

(remember, these go out great - heres syslog: )

```
nginxstaff postfix/smtpd[3388]: connect from mydomainother.com[1.1.1.1]
nginxstaff postfix/smtpd[3388]: B723B3F875: client=mydomainother.com[1.1.1.1]
nginxstaff postfix/cleanup[3390]: B723B3F875: message-id=<b9f2db02d8e5fdea9ac3970441bba901@test.mydomainother.com>
nginxstaff opendkim[3595]: B723B3F875: DKIM-Signature field added (s=mail, d=mydomainother.com)
nginxstaff postfix/qmgr[17564]: B723B3F875: from=<notifications@mydomainother.com>, size=602, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
nginxstaff postfix/smtpd[3388]: disconnect from mydomainother.com[1.1.1.1] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=7
nginxstaff postfix/smtp[3292]: B723B3F875: to=<myhomeaddress@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[108.177.96.27]:25, delay=0.61, delays=0.11/0/0.06/0.44, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1487950134 h61si10727491wrh.186 - gsmtp)
nginxstaff postfix/qmgr[17564]: B723B3F875: removed
```

the other domain is failing on SPF, and here's the DNS I have setup for the domain:

```
mydomain.com.   14400   IN  TXT v=spf1 ip4:181.224.128.60 mx a ip4:1.1.1.1/32 ip4:1.1.1.2 ip6:1111:1111:...0002/128 include:outlook.com ~all
mail._domainkey.mydomain.com.   600 IN  TXT v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCt79QysuOC7QU2h0w7eKSZyptVkZkPD/zqTqmzq3ZNpqz5YmunBatGhESYea5RX51CpQHbcH0gmAN0tXvz7jCIi+2xyDyVe+Ay/EW4D72DNU+a0Ckr6lPdsS0lpNg7A8/RzDO4+m2n1E7ZrImFp+3MZz6q5pQPm5DzqOoDCTTRnQIDAQAB; s=email
```

so basically, SPF and DNS entries are duplicated for both domains as the emails will be issuing forth from the same MTA and app server. 
So why does sending from mydomain.com do this :

```
nginxstaff postfix/smtpd[4905]: connect from mydomainother.com[1.1.1.1]
nginxstaff postfix/smtpd[4905]: 8E1C53F875: client=mydomainother.com[1.1.1.1]
nginxstaff postfix/cleanup[4908]: 8E1C53F875: message-id=<f79ea53783016295b221822c3916ab06@test.mydomainother.com>
nginxstaff opendkim[3595]: 8E1C53F875: DKIM-Signature field added (s=mail, d=mydomain.com)
nginxstaff postfix/qmgr[17564]: 8E1C53F875: from=<notifications@mydomain.com>, size=594, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
nginxstaff postfix/smtpd[4905]: disconnect from mydomainother.com[1.1.1.1] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=7
nginxstaff postfix/smtp[4909]: 8E1C53F875: to=<mypersonaladdress@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c03::1b]:25, 
delay=0.61, delays=0.09/0.01/0.08/0.43, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c03::1b] said: 
550-5.7.1 [1111:1111:...0002] Our system has detected that 550-5.7.1 this message does not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding 
PTR 550-5.7.1 records and authentication. Please review 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError 
for more information 550 5.7.1 . r30si10098207wrc.146 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
nginxstaff postfix/cleanup[4908]: 304423F878: message-id=<20170224154810.304423F878@servername>
nginxstaff postfix/qmgr[17564]: 304423F878: from=<>, size=3511, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
nginxstaff postfix/bounce[4910]: 8E1C53F875: sender non-delivery notification: 304423F878
nginxstaff postfix/qmgr[17564]: 8E1C53F875: removed
```